# Mass change product URL keys to match product names

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, url

Shopkeeper created configurable products by duplicating existing products and did not change the product URLs to match the product names. The shop is also a multilingual shop and different languages are made as store views.

This all lead to situation where the duplicated products had wrong url keys.

I found this code that could be added to a new .php file and run on the server and that was a solution for ONE store view:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$amount = 0;
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$products = $model->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $model->load($product->getId());
    $product->setUrlKey($model->getName())->save();
    set_time_limit();
    $amount++;
}
```

That code changed the product url keys to match the product names, but it only worked for one store view.

My question is: how do I change the product url keys for the other store views in other languages?

UPDATE!
The solution was easy: in the frontend just change to the next store view and run the new .php file in that view also.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why that worked, is because Magento internals will use the current store id on `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`.

You could have used `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId('STORE_ID');`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the improved code from the original question and taking into account the comments from @Tim Bezhashvyly regarding multiple store views.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId) { 
    $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();  
    $amount = 0;
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($_storeId);
    products = $model->getCollection();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $model->load($product->getId());
        $product->setUrlKey($model->getName())->save();
        set_time_limit(0);
        $amount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop through your store views using `Mage_Core_Model_App::getStores` method.

Comment: How would you apply this modification to the php code in the question?

Comment: Come on. It's easy. Get store views collection, inside of your products collection loop lop through store views collection and do your routine inside.