# URL key regenerating from tilte in magento 1.8 CE

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite, massaction

I have a magento 1.8  with 5 storeviews (IT -EN - DE- FR -ES)
I set the Italian (IT) as Default Store View.

Then I  figured out that, if i select "Default values" or "IT" store view  from the left dropdown "Choose Store View" menu in the Product page, the URL key are WRONG (some are from other products, some from other languages).

This happends just in these two store views. The others store view have the URL same to Title.

Is there a way to change in a massive way all the key urls in each store view so that they match the Title?

I tried reindexing a few time without success.

Comment: Is there a table i can trunate and recreate URL keys with reindex?

Comment: I tried following this post:
[link]http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/mass-change-product-url-keys-to-match-product-names
but didn't change situation
I just got an error  after some time it was running in shell

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1353

Answer (score 0):

You can re-generate your URL Keys per store view in a in a massive way using this extension, http://magendev.com/magento-extentions/url-key-master.html

it dose re-generation based on product name (page title).

see this video: http://magendev.com/urlkeymaster-doc/urlkeymaster-auto-generate.html