# Images replaced by placeholder image in frontend

Tags: magento-1.8, product-images, placeholder

All immages in frontend were replaced with placeholder image after running the scritp on this post:

[Mass change product URL keys to match product names](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/mass-change-product-url-keys-to-match-product-names)

No cache is active

Any idea why and how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the image cache? In System -> Cache Management -> Flush Catalog Images Cache? Probably the image cache is still active.

Comment: Yes, I flushed all cache, disabled chache, and refresh. 
The issue started after running the script. 
Before running the script I increased the following values 
php.ini memory_limit = 8192M;  
my.conf max_allowed_packet = 8M query_cache_size = 128M . but i don't think is related to that.

I also installed https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_StoreUrlRewrites

Comment: The script you mentioned doesn't do anything with images, so I doubt if that's the cause. But maybe decrease the limits you changed a bit, you don't need a memory limit of 8 gig.

Comment: Are you using flat tables? Are you able to see images in backend? If so, you need do reindex(since flat tables are not up to date)

Comment: I rolled back values in php.ini and my.conf. Unfortunately didn't change situation. I have also another Magento installation on same server, but its product images are working fine. Is there a way to debug and see why Magento is loading placeholder image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

The issue was related to memory_limit value in Plesk 12 vhost php setting.
Value was set to memory_limit = 1G ,  but looks like magento for some reason, don't  properly read value "1G" from the server configuration.

Once i set memory_limit = 1024M it started working again.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as accepted so that the question shows up as solved.

Comment: I tried but it say i must wait till tomorrow

Comment: Same problem same solution, thank you VERY much for taking the time to post it!